# Select a Page index while click on Arrow as per selected record in Multicolumn Combobox with Codeflex

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-flexbox

I am Using Flexbox for multiple Column grid in My Application. And When i have selected one record and Then by Clicking on Arrow i want all records and Page Index should be such that that current Selected Value should be Display.

**Steps**

**First**, Click on arrow and Show all records and Then i have moved to 2nd page index.(Screenshot Attached - Screen-1.png)
[image: screen-1]

**Second**, Then I have selected record (id - 9) which is on page index 2. Then click on Arrow as per Screenshot .Here i am showing whole record instead of Selected record only.(Screenshot Attached - Screen-2.png)
[image: screen-2]

**Third**, When i am clicking on Arrow then its showing me 1st Index Rather that 2nd index on which my Seleted record is there.So here i want to automatically select index 2..(Screenshot Attached - Screen-3.png)
[image: screen-3]

Waiting for your response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected list Page index while click on Arrow for Drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460157/selected-list-page-index-while-click-on-arrow-for-drop-down)

Comment: Yes, But i have got any proper solution for my problem.